# Métodos ExecuteReader(), ExecuteNonQuery() e ExecuteScalar(), quais são as diferenças e como utilizá-los?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou trabalhando com banco de dados **SQL Server** no C#, porem eu reparei que o objeto `SqlCommand` possui vários métodos para executar uma **query**, são eles: `ExecuteReader()`, `ExecuteNonQuery()` e `ExecuteScalar()`.

Minha duvida é a seguinte, quais são as diferenças entre esses métodos e como eu devo utilizá-los?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Usado para realizar uma leitura campo a campo em cima de uma extração de dados. Isto é feito através do objeto do tipo [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) devolvido pelo método.

Exemplo:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand("Select * from MinhaTabela", connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
        }
    }
}
```

É um método um pouco prolixo para acesso direto a colunas.

## [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Executa um comando que não traz uma relação de linhas e colunas. Seu retorno é, na verdade, a quantidade de linhas afetadas pelo comando.

É usado para sentenças como `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc.

Exemplo:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MinhaTabela set MeuCampo = 1 where OutroCampo = 2", connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    var registrosAfetados = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

## [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Executa um comando e traz como resultado a primeira coluna da primeira linha retornada. Costuma ser útil para executar, por exemplo, *Stored Procedures* que devolvam um determinado valor específico ou ainda funções como contagem de registros.

Exemplo:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(conn);
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MinhaTabela";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        var contagem = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cigano obrigado pela explicação, já esta me ajudando muito aqui, agora eu sei como aproveitar melhor esses métodos.

Comment: @Cigano bom explicação...

Comment: Apenas um detalhe na resposta do @Cigano.... o ExecuteNonQuery retorna o numero de linhas afetadas e não o numero de colunas. [Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @WemersonGuimarães Verdade. Obrigado!